# ASP.net MVC submit Button Adding Class issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I want to add style class to my submit button, like this I can use bootstrap Modal to show the result in this modal. This is my code :

```html
@model pfebs0.Models.StatModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    ...
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="mybtn" >Get</button>
        ..
}

<div id="modalDiv" class="modal fade" >
    <div class="modal-dialog"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $('.mybtn').click(function () {
                $('.modal-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                    $('#modalDiv').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: true
                    }, 'show');
                    bindForm(this);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The problem when I add the class `class="mybtn"` my form is not submitted any more when I click on it, If I remove `class="mybtn"` the button works fine. 
Also I have tried to use this : `<input type="submit" value="Create"  class="mybtn" />` but same problem

Comment: remove "return false;" from script tag

Comment: @Azim no this dosn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are returning false in your script, which prevents form to submit or go any further.

```
<script>$(function () {

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $('.mybtn').click(function () {
                $('.modal-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                    $('#modalDiv').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: true
                    }, 'show');
                    bindForm(this);
                });
                return false; // you should disable it or find another way to do 
            });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry but how to do that ?

Comment: Also Is it possible to send Data without using form ?